# Sum a range that changes depending on met criteria VBA

Tags: excel, vba, function, sum

I am attempting to create a Function where depending on specific criteria (Criteria is integer), it sums a specific range. It is not possible with SUMIFS because the SUM range will vary.

I was hoping to get some help as i cannot get it to sum said range.

I have this so far:

```
Function PrecioLic(Lic As Integer)

Select Case Lic

    Case "Licitante 1"
        PrecioLic = "=SUM(M13:M38)"
    Case "Licitante 2"
        PrecioLic = "=SUM(P13:P38)"
    Case "Licitante 3"
        PrecioLic = "=SUM(T13:T38)"
    Case "Licitante 4"
        PrecioLic = "=SUM(X13:X38)"
    Case "Licitante 5"
        PrecioLic = "=SUM(AB13:AB38)"
    Case "Licitante 6"
        PrecioLic = "=SUM(AF13:AF38)"
End Select
End Function
```

Comment: `PrecioLic = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("M13:M38"))` and so on

Comment: Also, if `Lic` is an integer, why are you doing a Select Case looking for a String?  Instead of `Case "Licitante 1"` it should probably just be `Case 1` and so on

Comment: And lastly, this can be done without VBA.  If your `Lic` number is in cell A1, then this formula would work just fine: `=SUM(INDEX($M$13:$AF$38,0,CHOOSE(A1,1,4,8,12,16,20)))`

Comment: Alternate: `=SUM(INDEX($M$13:$AF$38,0,MAX(1,(A1-1)*4)))`

Comment: Great, that worked perfectly, and you are correct  about the Integer, I messed up, I meant String. Thanks!!